# Syntax for andGroup and notExpression in the same json for GA4 filters

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, filterexpression

Could anyone provide a syntax for andGoup and notExpression in the same JSON for GA4 filters?

Answer (score 2):

Building on https://code.markedmondson.me/googleAnalyticsR/articles/reporting-ga4.html#examples-using-ga4-filters and https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/FilterExpression

For the filter `(field1 == "match_me" AND field2 != "do_not_match_me")`, something like should work:

```json
{
  "andGroup": {
    "expressions": [
      {
        "filter": {
          "fieldName": "field1",
          "stringFilter": {
            "matchType": "EXACT", // not sure of the format here
            "value": "match_me"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "notExpression": {
          "filter": {
            "fieldName": "field2",
            "stringFilter": {
              "matchType": "EXACT", // not sure of the format here
              "value": "do_not_match_me"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just one filter then go with this:

```
dimension_filter=FilterExpression(
   not_expression=FilterExpression(
        filter=Filter(
            field_name="transactionId",
               string_filter=Filter.StringFilter(value="(not set)"),
                )
        )
),
```

We use and_group when using two filters combine them. Here is an example:

```
dimension_filter=FilterExpression(
    and_group=FilterExpressionList(
        expressions=[
            FilterExpression(
                not_expression=FilterExpression(
                filter=Filter(
                    field_name="eventName",
                    string_filter=Filter.StringFilter(
                        match_type=Filter.StringFilter.MatchType.CONTAINS,
                        value="in_app_purchase",
                    ),
                ))
            ),
            FilterExpression(
                not_expression=FilterExpression(
                filter=Filter(
                    field_name="eventName",
                    string_filter=Filter.StringFilter(
                        match_type=Filter.StringFilter.MatchType.CONTAINS,
                        value="first_open",
                    ),
                ))
            ),
        ]
    )
),
```